# sound and brightness notification lost

Tags: sound, brightness, notification

i don't know what happened specifically but now i faced a sudden disappearance of sound level notification and also the brightness level notification and the notification style now changed to one that is not unity's

i have vivid and using unity

NOTE: that happens on all desktop environments not unity only (mate , gnome, gnome-classic , unity)

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution:

Code:
gksudo gedit /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.xfce.xfce4-notifyd.Notifications.service

After that change line :

Code:
Exec=/usr/lib/xfce4/notifyd/xfce4-notifyd

With:
Code:
Exec=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/notify-osd

Answer (score 0):

Use this command, logout and login

```
unity --reset-icons
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: sorry, i didn't say the sound icon on menu bar i meant the notification that appears on volume change

Answer (score 0):

In System Settings -> Sound make sure the box shown at bottom left (show sound volume in the menu bar) is checked. If this doesn't work, run the following command in the terminal:

`gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.sound visible true`